# Is there any easy method available to know whether there is a change in schema in Salesforce by using API?

Tags: java, api, salesforce

There is a **getUpdated()** method available with partner API to get the list of updated records for each object in Salesforce, But is there a way to do the same thing with Schema?

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/How-to-I-get-the-last-modified-date-of-a-custom-object-or-field/td-p/237501/highlight/false

The above link exactly explains my problem :( no solution though!

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

1. Write some script over the ANT-based "Migration Tool" that would periodically download whole metadata, commit changes to SVN? Read about "[retrieveCode](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_deploying_ant_retrieveCode.htm)" operation (not the best name in the world. But since it accepts package.xml as config source I believe you can rely on it to retrieve objects too).
2. Automate access to https://instance.salesforce.com/setup/build/webservices.apexp. Especially the Enterprise WSDL ( https://instance.salesforce.com/soap/wsdl.jsp?type=* ) should be good for data model changes. And again - you'd need something to detect differences between the files.
3. Really weird idea - can you try to automate screen-scraping of the [Setup Audit Trail](https://na5.salesforce.com/setup/org/orgsetupaudit.jsp) page? Or manually download the csv, then feed it to small processing program (even excel sheet should do). This one will actually list the changes for you but the format isn't best suited to parse out what was changed...

---

*Safe harbor blah blah blah*

Let's hope the upcoming Tooling API will deal with it better. There are gossips on releasing improved API, rewriting the Eclipse "Force.com IDE" plugin and releasing it to the community...

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) 

Honestly, I don't understand the first point, I'll look into 2nd one. And 3rd one :D cool idea even-though its really weird :)

I'm a fledgeling in Salesforce, so forgive me for me naivety.

Comment: Re #1: Have you used "Eclipse IDE", "Force.com IDE" or maybe Brainengine so far? Or maybe any other programmer in your team had? These tools are used mainly by developers to write and deploy customized code to Force.com platform. They can be also used to retrieve & modify the metadata (which is the part that you're interested in most). Sorry if it sounded too technical ]:> Try to play with Eclipse, if it will help you to retrieve metadata then you can make next step to "Migration Tool" to automate the process.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using JBossDevStudio almost same as Eclipse IDE. I'm writing standalone Java classes to perform schema replication. I'm using partner.jar generated from partner.wsdl and wsc.jar . Using meta data api there is a method to change the schema but all I want is the last modified field of each sObject :( , I'll anyways try implementing your 3rd suggestion :)